# convert data from database into a list

Tags: php, javascript

I want to retrieve latitude and longitude from my database and show them as maker on Google Map. I learned it from [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example). But in this example, the latitude and longitude is assigned by user. I want to know if I have already retrieved my lat&long from my database, for example in php, `$lat $long`, how to assign them into a list like this:

```
var locations=[[..,..],[..,..],[..,..]]
//$lat is the first parameter and $long is the second.
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little pseudo code that should get you are your way.

```
$results = array();
while($row = $query->getResult()){
     $results[] = array($row["place_name"],
                        $row["latitude"],
                        $row["longitude"],
                        $row["id"]); 

}
?>
var locations = <?= json_encode($results); ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I change to  <?php
        $exe1 = "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM car";
        $result1 = mysql_query($exe1, $db) or die(mysql_error());
        $location = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
            $location[] = array(
                $row["latitude"],
                $row["longitude"],
            );
        }
        ?>var locations = <?= json_encode($results); ?>; it can work!~

Answer (score 0):

you can store multidimensional arrays in php. [Here is the example link](http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php).

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd just echo the values in place, like so:

```
var locations = [<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($lat); $i++) {
        if ($i > 0) echo ",";
        echo "[" . $lat[$i] . "],[" . $long[$i] . "]";
    }
?>];
```